# Advice how to connect custom database with Wordpress, change data in Wordpress and finaly use this data

Tags: customization, custom-field, database

Is it possible to create a page in WordPress that will allow logged-in users to create new or change existing content from the custom database?

So I think this task could be divided into three parts:

- how to connect a custom database with WordPress?
- how to create a separate page in WordPress where users will be able to change the content from the custom database (best with some forms)?
- create a menu where I will use this data (I plan to do this via a child theme)

Can someone give me quick advice on where to start journey -> can this be done through Plugins (and which ones) or do I need to write PHP functions for this or some other technique?

Basically, I need to create an extensive menu where over 200 dishes will be presented (using data from the custom database) but the client wants to be able to change the data in some form.

I have experience with frontend, PHP, and MySQL but I only know the basics behind WordPress

Comment: Is there a specific need to keep the dishes in the custom database? If not, you'd likely be better off migrating the data into WordPress as a custom post type, and just letting them use the regular WP editor interface to make updates as needed.

Comment: I agree with @WebElaine here that a custom post-type is the way to go as I don't see any reason from your question to build a custom database table... ...the 200 dishes is sort of what WP CPTs are designed to manage.  If you MUST however, it can be done, I'd start by familiarizing yourself with `$wpdb->` functions and how to perpare SQL statements before using them. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/  Beyond that what you're asking is pretty comprehensive and should be broken up into steps. Also check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/

Comment: @WebElaine  Actually no, but can I then use that custom post type in my custom html code which I plan to insert into the Wordpress as menu (using the Child theme technique)

Comment: If I understand your comment, yes, you can add links to that custom post type in the menu.